# The type JComboBox is not generic

Tags: java, swing, generics, jcombobox, java-7

I have a problem. I doing on debug a program. When I copy the program and import into my Eclipse, there are some error. One of the error is I cannot set parameter of the JComboBox with < String >. But it shows no error in my friend's Eclipse. We both using same jre1.7.

```
private JComboBox<String> pathComboBox = null;

private JComboBox<String> bodyComboBox = null;

//Error: The type JComboBox is not generic; It cannot be parameterized with argument <String>. 
//So I believe this is not the JRE problem.
```

Comment: Check whether you have no earlier versions of the Java libraries in your class path.

Comment: "We both using same jre1.7" evidently not.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're both using JRE 1.7 and (more importantly) are your IDEs both set to compile against 1.7?  I have 1.6 and 1.7 installed on my dev machine, but I set Eclipse to compile against 1.6.  Open Eclipse > Project Menu > Properties menu item > Java Compiler > Compiler Compliance Level = 1.7

Comment: Yes....Double checked..Both using 1.7....For MarsAtomic, I have set it to 1.7 as well..

Comment: Hmmmm....I have fixed the problem. I just install latest JDK 7 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when I imported a swing project to an older java version environment.
 Check if your eclipse is correctly configured to use a java7 SDK.

You should check your project facets.

As you can see here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html

Comment: I using latest Juno Eclipse. I just copied my friend's eclipse, and his eclipse is also juno version. I use his eclipse to import the project, everthing is same...

Comment: Hmmmm....I have fixed the problem. I just install latest JDK 7 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html